# Cannot connect mongodb and socket.io using node

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Y6mWhcdSUM) tutorial to make a basic socket.io chatroom connected to mongodb. Here is the code:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = require('socket.io').listen(3000).sockets;

// Connect to mongo
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', function(err, db){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('MongoDB connected...');

    // Connect to Socket.io
    client.on('connection',   function(socket){
        let chat = db.collection('chats');

        // Create function to send status
        sendStatus = function(s){
            socket.emit('status', s);
        }

        // Get chats from mongo collection
        chat.find().limit(100).sort({_id:1}).toArray(function(err, res){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }

            // Emit the messages
            socket.emit('output', res);
        });

        // Handle input events
        socket.on('input', function(data){
            let name = data.name;
            let message = data.message;

            // Check for name and message
            if(name == '' || message == ''){
                // Send error status
                sendStatus('Please enter a name and message');
            } else {
                // Insert message
                chat.insert({name: name, message: message}, function(){
                    client.emit('output', [data]);

                    // Send status object
                    sendStatus({
                        message: 'Message sent',
                        clear: true
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        // Handle clear
        socket.on('clear', function(data){
            // Remove all chats from collection
            chat.remove({}, function(){
                // Emit cleared
                socket.emit('cleared');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The code runs and I get

> (node:31737) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   MongoDB connected...

But when I try to get the html page in browser I get `This 127.0.0.1 page can’t be found` instead.

Here is the index.html page on the same folder as server.js that is supposed to be rendered but it does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>MongoChat</title>
    <style>
        #messages{height:300px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">
                    MongoChat 
                    <button id="clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
                </h1>
                <div id="status"></div>
                <div id="chat">
                    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name...">
                    <br>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div id="messages" class="card-block">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <textarea id="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message..."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function(){
            var element = function(id){
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }
            // Get Elements
            var status = element('status');
            var messages = element('messages');
            var textarea = element('textarea');
            var username = element('username');
            var clearBtn = element('clear');
            // Set default status
            var statusDefault = status.textContent;
            var setStatus = function(s){
                // Set status
                status.textContent = s;
                if(s !== statusDefault){
                    var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                        setStatus(statusDefault);
                    }, 4000);
                }
            }
            // Connect to socket.io
            var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:4000');
            // Check for connection
            if(socket !== undefined){
                console.log('Connected to socket...');
                // Handle Output
                socket.on('output', function(data){
                    //console.log(data);
                    if(data.length){
                        for(var x = 0;x < data.length;x++){
                            // Build out message div
                            var message = document.createElement('div');
                            message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                            message.textContent = data[x].name+": "+data[x].message;
                            messages.appendChild(message);
                            messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                        }
                    }
                });
                // Get Status From Server
                socket.on('status', function(data){
                    // get message status
                    setStatus((typeof data === 'object')? data.message : data);
                    // If status is clear, clear text
                    if(data.clear){
                        textarea.value = '';
                    }
                });
                // Handle Input
                textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                    if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey == false){
                        // Emit to server input
                        socket.emit('input', {
                            name:username.value,
                            message:textarea.value
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                })
                // Handle Chat Clear
                clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    socket.emit('clear');
                });
                // Clear Message
                socket.on('cleared', function(){
                    messages.textContent = '';
                });
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- mongodb driver `"mongodb": "^3.1.0-beta4",`
- mongodb database version `v3.2.20`
- "socket.io": "^2.1.1"`

This problem bugs me for hours and I have no clues. So apprecite your help.

Comment: What is the question? You get a log message showing the database is connected. The "warning" is nothing to do with not connecting.

Comment: The warning is not the problem. The problem is that why the html page is not loaded?

Comment: What page? There is no page being served here. If you have other code, then it belongs in the question. As does being clear about what the question is actually asking. The database is clearly connected from the logged message you put inside the callback. If there was no connection then you would not see that. Therefore there is not really any point talking about that point. Keep your question to the topic. But if you are expecting to connect a browser to "just this code", then you need to keep reading the tutorial because nothing here is doing that at this point.